# java paypal merchant sdk recurring payment invalid token

Tags: java, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal

Hi I'm trying to create a Paypal Recurring Pyament using the JAVA Merhant SDK but I keep having "invalid token" when trying to call "createRecurringPaymentsProfile" method.

Here are the Request and Response

For SetExpressCheckout Request

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"
              xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes"
              xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes">
<soapenv:Header>
    <ns:RequesterCredentials>
        <ebl:Credentials>
            <ebl:Username>XXX</ebl:Username>
            <ebl:Password>XXX</ebl:Password>
            <ebl:Signature>XXX</ebl:Signature>
        </ebl:Credentials>
    </ns:RequesterCredentials>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns:SetExpressCheckoutReq>
        <ns:SetExpressCheckoutRequest>
            <ebl:Version>109.0</ebl:Version>
            <ebl:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails>
                <ebl:ReturnURL>http://127.0.0.1:8888/ReturnURL</ebl:ReturnURL>
                <ebl:CancelURL>http://127.0.0.1:8888/CancelURL</ebl:CancelURL>
                <ebl:BillingAgreementDetails>
                    <ebl:BillingType>RecurringPayments</ebl:BillingType>
                    <ebl:BillingAgreementDescription>Buyer is billed at &quot;USD1.00&quot; per month
                    </ebl:BillingAgreementDescription>
                </ebl:BillingAgreementDetails>
                <ebl:PaymentDetails>
                    <ebl:OrderTotal currencyID="USD">1.00</ebl:OrderTotal>
                    <ebl:ItemTotal currencyID="USD">1</ebl:ItemTotal>
                    <ebl:ButtonSource>PayPal_SDK</ebl:ButtonSource>
                    <ebl:NotifyURL>/NotifyURL</ebl:NotifyURL>
                    <ebl:PaymentAction>Sale</ebl:PaymentAction>
                </ebl:PaymentDetails>
            </ebl:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails>
        </ns:SetExpressCheckoutRequest>
    </ns:SetExpressCheckoutReq>
</soapenv:Body>
```

This the response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes"
                   xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility"
                   xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                   xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes"
                   xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xsi:type="wsse:SecurityType"></Security>
        <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xsi:type="ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType">
            <Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:UserIdPasswordType">
                <Username xsi:type="xs:string"></Username>
                <Password xsi:type="xs:string"></Password>
                <Signature xsi:type="xs:string"></Signature>
                <Subject xsi:type="xs:string"></Subject>
            </Credentials>
        </RequesterCredentials>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0">
        <SetExpressCheckoutResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
            <Timestamp xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">2014-04-05T22:23:40Z</Timestamp>
            <Ack xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Success</Ack>
            <CorrelationID xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">6c19207a14fd</CorrelationID>
            <Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">109.0</Version>
            <Build xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">10463669</Build>
            <Token xsi:type="ebl:ExpressCheckoutTokenType">EC-1X212344K9178491M</Token>
        </SetExpressCheckoutResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"
                  xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes"
                  xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns:RequesterCredentials>
            <ebl:Credentials>
                <ebl:Username>XXX</ebl:Username>
                <ebl:Password>XXX</ebl:Password>
                <ebl:Signature>XXX</ebl:Signature>
            </ebl:Credentials>
        </ns:RequesterCredentials>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq>
            <ns:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest>
                <ebl:Version>109.0</ebl:Version>
                <ebl:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails>
                    <ebl:Token>EC-1X212344K9178491M</ebl:Token>
                    <ebl:RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails>
                        <ebl:BillingStartDate>2014-04-06T13:21:36Z</ebl:BillingStartDate>
                    </ebl:RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails>
                    <ebl:ScheduleDetails>
                        <ebl:Description>Buyer is billed at &quot;USD1.00&quot; per month</ebl:Description>
                        <ebl:PaymentPeriod>
                            <ebl:BillingPeriod>Month</ebl:BillingPeriod>
                            <ebl:BillingFrequency>12</ebl:BillingFrequency>
                            <ebl:Amount currencyID="USD">1.00</ebl:Amount>
                        </ebl:PaymentPeriod>
                    </ebl:ScheduleDetails>
                </ebl:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails>
            </ns:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest>
        </ns:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The response was an "invalid token"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes"
                   xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility"
                   xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                   xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes"
                   xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xsi:type="wsse:SecurityType"></Security>
        <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xsi:type="ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType">
            <Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:UserIdPasswordType">
                <Username xsi:type="xs:string"></Username>
                <Password xsi:type="xs:string"></Password>
                <Signature xsi:type="xs:string"></Signature>
                <Subject xsi:type="xs:string"></Subject>
            </Credentials>
        </RequesterCredentials>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0">
        <CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
            <Timestamp xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">2014-04-05T22:28:11Z</Timestamp>
            <Ack xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Failure</Ack>
            <CorrelationID xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">50e773299b36f</CorrelationID>
            <Errors xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:ErrorType">
                <ShortMessage xsi:type="xs:string">Invalid Token</ShortMessage>
                <LongMessage xsi:type="xs:string">The token is invalid</LongMessage>
                <ErrorCode xsi:type="xs:token">11502</ErrorCode>
                <SeverityCode xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Error</SeverityCode>
            </Errors>
            <Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">109.0</Version>
            <Build xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">10433064</Build>
            <CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetails xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"
                                                           xsi:type="ebl:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetailsType">
                <ProfileID xsi:type="xs:string"></ProfileID>
                <TransactionID xsi:type="xs:string"></TransactionID>
            </CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetails>
        </CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm sure that the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile Request token is the response token from SetExpressCheckout.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question.

OrderTotal should be seto to "0" and ItemTotal should be removed in SetExpressCheckout Request.

But the "invalid token error" is not very helpful error message.

Answer (score 0):

After you SetExpressCheckOutResponse include the following code,

```
Map<String, String> sdkConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();
sdkConfig.put("mode", "sandbox");

sdkConfig.put("mode", "sandbox");
sdkConfig.put("acct1.UserName", apiUsername);
sdkConfig.put("acct1.Password", apiPassword);
sdkConfig.put("acct1.Signature", apiSignature);

SimpleDateFormat formatterR = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:sssz");

CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq createRecurringPaymentsProfileReq = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq();
CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType createRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType();

RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType recurringPaymentsProfileDetails = new RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType();
recurringPaymentsProfileDetails.setBillingStartDate(formatterR.format(new Date()));
recurringPaymentsProfileDetails.setSubscriberName("YOUR SUBSCRIBER NAME");

BasicAmountType billingAmount = new BasicAmountType(CurrencyCodeType.USD, "1.00");
//I Take as MONTHLY Recurrence
//So that i set periodType as MONTH, frequency as 1 (for every month) and billing amount here i sent as 1 USD
BillingPeriodDetailsType paymentPeriod = new BillingPeriodDetailsType(BillingPeriodType.MONTH, Integer.parseInt("1"), billingAmount);
ScheduleDetailsType scheduleDetails = new ScheduleDetailsType("Description about payment", paymentPeriod); //description, paymentPeriod object              
CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType createRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType(recurringPaymentsProfileDetails, scheduleDetails);

AddressType addressType = new AddressType();
addressType.setStateOrProvince("STATE");
addressType.setCityName("CITY");
addressType.setCountryName("COUNTRY");

PersonNameType personName = new PersonNameType();
personName.setFirstName("SUBSCRIBER FIRST NAME");
personName.setLastName("SUBSCRIBER LAST NAME");

PayerInfoType payerInfoType = new PayerInfoType();
payerInfoType.setAddress(addressType);
payerInfoType.setPayerName(personName);

                CreditCardDetailsType creditCard = new CreditCardDetailsType();
                //creditCard.setCreditCardType(CreditCardTypeType.VISA);

                // Credit Card Number
                creditCard.setCreditCardNumber("CARD NO");//4442662639546634

                // Credit Card Expiration Month
                creditCard.setExpMonth(12);//Integer.parseInt("12")

                // Credit Card Expiration Year
                creditCard.setExpYear(Integer.parseInt(2016);//Integer.parseInt("2016")
                creditCard.setCVV2("CVV CODE");
                creditCard.setCardOwner(payerInfoType);
                createRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails.setCreditCard(creditCard);

                createRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest
                        .setCreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails(createRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails);
                createRecurringPaymentsProfileReq
                        .setCreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest(createRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest);

                PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = null;
                try {
                    service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(sdkConfig);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.info("Error Message : " + e.getMessage());
                }
                CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType createRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse = null;
                try {
                    // ## Making API call
                    // Invoke the appropriate method corresponding to API in service
                    // wrapper object
                     createRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse = service
                            .createRecurringPaymentsProfile(createRecurringPaymentsProfileReq);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.info("Error Message : " + e.getMessage());
                }

                String ProfileID = "";
                // ## Accessing response parameters
                // You can access the response parameters using getter methods in
                // response object as shown below
                // ### Success values
                if (createRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse.getAck().getValue()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

                    // A unique identifier for future reference to the details of
                    // this recurring payment.
                    ProfileID = createRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse
                            .getCreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetails()
                            .getProfileID();
                    LOGGER.info("Profile ID:"+ProfileID);
                    //mes = "approved";
                }
                // ### Error Values
                // Access error values from error list using getter methods
                else {
                    List<ErrorType> errorList = createRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse
                            .getErrors();
                    LOGGER.info("API Error Message : "
                            + errorList.get(0).getLongMessage());
                    //mes = "error";
                }
```

I hope this will helps you...